# Rounding a number to Decimal places

Tags: javascript

I have lat lng co-ordinates that are fetched from an api so I can put them in a span. The issue I have is that the co-ordinates are whatever value are entered through the api and I output them on the page.

```
<div id="co-ordinates">
<strong>Coordinates</strong>
<span class="lat"><%= @camera.deep_fetch(:location, :lat) {} %></span>
<span class="lng"><%= @camera.deep_fetch(:location, :lng) {} %></span>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can then use javascript to limit the decimal places of the co-ordinate value to 6 places?

Comment: <%= - is server-side script tag, round them in server-side code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what server-side code you're running, but something like this would work in .Net:

```
 <%= Math.Round(@camera.deep_fetch(:location, :lat) {}, 6) %>
```

If that doesn't work, you could write server-side functions that call the @camera and get its lat and long - and then return them, rounded to 6 decimal places.  Something like this:

Server-Side (these need to be public):  You will need to write the GetCamera... functions, obviously:

```
public decimal LatRounded(int decimalPlaces)
{
    return Math.Round(GetCameraLatFunction(), decimalPlaces);
}

public decimal LongRounded(int decimalPlaces)
{
    return Math.Round(GetCameraLongFunction(), decimalPlaces);
}
```

Then you would call this from your page like this:

```
<div id="co-ordinates">
<strong>Coordinates</strong>
<span class="lat"><%= LatRounded(6) %></span>
<span class="lng"><%= LongRounded(6) %></span>
</div>
```